# iTunes Connect submission error: Invalid Binary

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

[image]
[image]
I checked the cetificate and provisioning profile,and make sure they are distribution mode. 
But upload to the iTunes Connect ,it always prompt me :invalid binary! So can guys help me,what can I do? And where I can contact the apple supporting team？ Thanks for you all.

Comment: which Xcode version you are using?

Comment: Xcode 7.3,is it impact?

Comment: try again. lot of users facing similar issue.

Comment: try with application loader

Comment: Validate binary in " Organiser " and check

Answer (score 0):

I had try to check my boss's mail,and I found the reply of the apple.

Non-public API usage:

The app references non-public selectors in Chedeer_Merchant: setGeometryDelegate:

And I solve it.